# Should I buffer my switch button input?

Tags: voltage, fpga, voltage-divider, debounce, external

I have external switch with 24v/open circuit.
I think that I only need voltage divider and drive the FPGA input, but something feels weird for me, maybe I need some capacitor for noise? maybe some buffer to protect the FPGA?
[image]
EDIT:
Please see the attached DC electrical characteristics
On my board when external switch leaved the voltage will be ~0v
when pressed the voltage will be 24*1.5/12.5= ~2.9V
[image]

Comment: Do you plan to debounce it in the FPGA?

Comment: Are you sure that will even present the FPGA with correct logic voltage levels?

Comment: @Justme please see my edit

Comment: ESD protection etc. is pretty important to consider if it is an external connection.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of example input circuits.  Just google it.
Some very simplistic ones are below.  You can keep adding more to them as you want to add more protection, or debouncing etc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUTuwt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You should consider adding ESD protection devices, such as TVS (Transient Voltage Suppression) diodes, to your input lines.

To filter out noise caused by switch toggling, you can add a small capacitance to smooth the input signal before it reaches the FPGA.

Comment: can you show me how to connect it ?